# setVisibleMapRect working unpredictably with edgePadding

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to display a route on a map. I have it defined nicely as :

```
self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
```

This is how the route is displayed:

[image]

I wanted to have around 5px of padding on each side so I added

```
self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5), animated: true)
```

But then the map zooms out much more:

[image]

Even if I do

```
self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), animated: true)
```

The result is like this:

[image]

How does it work? Is there a way to add just a little bit of padding, without the map zooming out so much?

Comment: try animated: false once

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal Actually, when I do animated: false on setRegion function it behaves as expected. I still don't understand why it works like that though.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452461-setvisiblemaprect

Comment: I can google documentation. ;) 
But what does the fact that I want the transition to be animated have to do with what map size I end up with?

Comment: If you want to change the center coordinate without changing the zoom level, use the setCenter(_:animated:) instead

Answer (score 1):

I see that the question is old, but I had a similar problem and did not find an answer to it here. Therefore, I will write what helped me.
In my case, when the indent was changed, the picture remained the same.

It helped me to move the call of `setRegion(_:animated:)` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

After that, everything turns out to be configured.